# Piping console.log() contents to a .txt file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log, lighthouse

I have a Node.js file that outputs a bunch of test results, easily >1000 lines, to Terminal. The file looks something like this:

`launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('https://www.apple.com/', flags).then(results => { console.log(results); });`

The `console.log()` is only there because I couldn't figure out another way to view the results. I need a way to create a file through Node.js, not the command line, that contains all of the CLI output/results.

I thought that `fs.appendFile('example.txt', 'append this text to the file', (err) => {});` could be of use, but what I need to "append" to the file is the function's `results`. When I try that, the file only contains [object Object] instead of the actual results of the tests.

I'm a beginner to Node, any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are appending the results object to the file. Maybe try passing JSON.stringify(results) to the file to get a json format view.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I had to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you need to include the appendFile inside of your other function. This assumes that your 'results' object is of the string type. If not then you need to get the string version of this object.

The lighthouse docs specify the format of the log information that is returned. If you add `output: json` to the flags object then you can use it lik

```
launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('https://www.apple.com/', flags).then(results => { 
    fs.appendFile('example.txt', JSON.stringify(results), (err) => {
        console.log('error appending to file example.txt');
    });
});
```